# Call wcf soap service from php with multiple parameters (not as an array)

Tags: c#, php, wcf, soap, parameters

Good day everyone,
i wonder if there a way to call a soap wcf service's function with multiple parameters from a php client?

I know you can embed the parameters in an array and then call a function. But sadly my need is to write a service which is compatible with existing php clients. And those do call the functions with separate parameters.
So i need to response to requests like this:

```
 $soapClient = new SoapClient('http://myService?wsdl', $options);
 $param1 = 1;
 $param2 = 2;
 $soapClient->doGoodThingsInTheNameOfTheMoon($param1, $param2);
```

but the wcf service i wrote can response just to

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient('http://myService?wsdl', $options);
$soapClient->doGoodThingsInTheNameOfTheMoon(array("param1"=>1,"param2"=> 2));
```

My service looks like following:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ImyserviceBinding
{

    [OperationContract]
    bool doGoodThingsInTheNameOfTheMoon(Param param1, Param param2);
}
```

with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes set by the Datatypes

So i need to downgrade to a specific wcf version? Or specify some behavior in the *.config file?

web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" name="myService.myService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          contract="ImyserviceBinding" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:60000/myService.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thank for any advice!